# After unsubscribing, should I still have access to Foxtel on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

On my Xbox Live account a while back I had Foxtel. I got over it / didn't have time for it after a couple months of paying for this service and I removed it from my account.

I haven't been charged for it since, so I'm considering it closed / null / void.

Last night out of pure being too tired to think properly I selected Foxtel from the main menu, which has recently been updated interface wise.

I didn't realize until about 20 minutes later but I was able to view quite a number of channels even though I didn't have a Foxtel subscription.

I'm now concerned that this has automatically resubscribed me to my old plan and will begin charging me.

Is this the case, or are there just a few channels that are free? (Seems weird if so). I thought it might deduct Microsoft Points or similar per hour but that doesn't seem to have been the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's unlikely that accessing the app resubscribed you to a former service level, it's probably best to double check and make sure.  The only way to access the Xbox integration settings for Foxtel is via the [Foxtel website](https://www.foxtel.com.au/distauth/UI/Login?realm=External&goto=https://www.foxtel.com.au/my-foxtel/default.htm).

Supposedly Sky News is [free to anyone](http://www.foxtel.com.au/xbox/default.htm) who has the Foxtel app on their Xbox, so if that's all you managed to access, you might have been just playing with a free preview.

Beyond that I'd suggest calling them during normal business hours, using one of the [phone numbers](http://www.foxtel.com.au/about-foxtel/contact/default.htm) on their website.

It's entirely possible that it's a mistake in your favor, but that's usually not the way these things tend to go, and getting any charges sorted out now is going to be easier than waiting to see if you ever get a bill.